# Why is header guard ineffective when including stb_image?

Tags: c++

I want to use stb_image library, which the author has put into a very large header file. 
To use the library, the documentation tells me to add these 2 lines to my code.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

I did just that, putting it into a header file; I even made sure that it has include guard.

```
#ifndef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#endif
```

The linker complained however.

I look up and find the solution.
https://github.com/nothings/stb/issues/3

Basically, I have to add the two lines above to the cpp file and not header file. It works like a charm. 
But why is header guard not effective in this way? I have been reading about translation units and statics yet I could not understand why my method would not work.

Comment: Header guards only prevent multiple inclusion within a single translation unit. Every new run of the compiler  starts fresh and has no idea that another file already included a given header. Since you got a linker error my suspicion is stb_image.h contains some variable definitions or similar and since you likely had multiple cpp files including your header, they replicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stb_image.h has its own include guards.  That's not what defining `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` is for.  Defining `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` tells stb_image.h to include not only *declarations*, but also *definitions* for its functions and variables into that translation unit.  If stb_image.h is included into multiple translation units with `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` defined, then all of those translation units will have definitions for stb_image's functions and variables, and the One Definition Rule is violated.